# Remotely accessing the host using SSH

Tags: ssh

I am working on a project and for that project I need a software which is on my university server. Before I was working in my laboratory. Due to some personal reason I had to leave the country. Before leaving I setup SSH and VNC on my host computer which is a linux machine with Centos distribution. After I left the country I used to access my host computer from my home country using putty and VNC viewer. Yesterday when I tried to SSH onto my host I got this Error: " Software caused connection abort". I asked the system administrator in my university and he told me that SSH is blocked for outside the country. The only solution for you is to be inside the university network first and then access the host using putty and VNC.

Can someone please walk me through how can I do this.

Comment: You can try to access to some (semi-shady) proxy first which is inside the country. Maybe this is a question for SuperUser.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to use a VPN that is located within the same country.  That way the university servers think you are logging in from within the country.

For example, I am in Brazil, but when I use my US VPN most websites see me as coming from the US.

Comment: Dear Sir, I can log in to my computer using SSH and VPN. Now the problem I am having is in VNC to view the remote desktop. On the server I have VNC server running. I can log in to my VNC SERVER using my credentials. But once I log in I can see a black screen. Any suggestion where I am having problem.?

Comment: I haven't used VNC in a few years so I cannot answer that.

Comment: Al right. Thank You. Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need to find a host in your university country and connect to that host first. Then login in to your university laboratory via that host.